# Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, rbenv

When I changed my Gemfile version to 2.6.3, I got the error message "Your Ruby version is 2.7.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3", and when I changed my Gemfile version to 2.7.2, I got the error message "Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2".

When I run rails in my home directory, it works, but when I run in my specific directory, it gives me the error messages above, and my ruby version keeps switching from 2.6.3 and 2.7.2 even though when I run ruby -v I get ruby 2.7.2p137.

I've tried all the solutions I could find, like running bundle install and updating my path, but I can't find the solution. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

This is my gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.2 (2020-10-01 patchlevel 137) [x86_64-darwin19]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/yeanjyoo/.gem
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/yeanjyoo/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/yeanjyoo/.gem/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/yeanjyoo/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-19
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/yeanjyoo/.gem
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/bin/ruby
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
     - /Users/yeanjyoo/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/yeanjyoo/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/bin
     - /usr/local/pgsql/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
```

This is my path: echo $PATH

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Users/yeanjyoo/.rbenv/bin:/Users/yeanjyoo/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/bin:/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Are you using a version manager, such as rvm or asdf?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I'm using rbenv